# Error when using AngularJS component inside Angular app: "Error: Trying to get the AngularJS injector before it being set."

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-upgrade

I'm working through Angular's [upgrade guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) to learn how to embed AngularJS components in an Angular app.  I've created a bare-bones Angular app using the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) and added a simple AngularJS module as a dependency.

When I run `ng serve`, the application compiles with no errors. However, at runtime, I get this message in the console:

```
Error: Trying to get the AngularJS injector before it being set.
```

What is causing this error, and how can I avoid it?  I haven't deviated from the steps detailed in the upgrade guide.

Here's how I'm upgrading my AngularJS component inside my Angular app:

```
// example.directive.ts
import { Directive, ElementRef, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

// this is the npm module that contains the AngularJS component
import { MyComponent } from '@my-company/module-test';

@Directive({
    selector: 'my-upgraded-component'
})
export class ExampleDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {

        // the .injectionName property is the component's selector
        // string; "my-component" in this case.
        super(MyComponent.injectionName, elementRef, injector);
    }
}
```

And here's my `app.module.ts`:

```
// app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { ExampleDirective } from './example.directive';
import { myModuleName } from '@my-company/module-test';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, ExampleDirective],
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, UpgradeModule],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) {}
    ngDoBootstrap() {
        this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [myModuleName], {
            strictDi: true
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using Angular 5.2.0.

Comment: Why is the import statement different for each file when referencing `@my-company/module-test`? It also doesn't look like you do anything with the imported `MyComponent` in the first file.

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash - I was simplifying the example a bit, but I've updated my question to show why I import the component; it's so that I can reference the component's selector string which is stored as a property on the component class.

The two files import different things from `@my-company/module-test` because the module exports multiple named exports.

Comment: I've opened an issue on Angular's GitHub here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23141

Comment: i have same issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyvy53

Comment: I got this error when I imported the `UpgradeModule` in more than one NgModule. Once I removed that, it went away.

Comment: @Amin Rahimi: You need to <head> and <body> tags to your Stackblitz html and place the script references to (jquery &) angular in the <head> section.

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue, and finally solved it. There are some steps to follow before bootstrap an hybrid Angular/angularjs application.

1. Install the UpgradeModule `npm install @angular/upgrade`
2. Wrap your "CompanyModule" (the module where all your company components are registered) into a new angularjs module (for instance: Ng1Shared). If you not have a module for your company components, it must be created. Than downgrade AppComponent as shown below.

   ```
   const MyCompanyModule = angular
      .module('MyCompanyModule', [])
      .component('myComponent', MyComponent)
      .name;


   const Ng1Shared = angular
      .module('Ng1Shared', [MyCompanyModule])
      .directive('appRoot', downgradeComponent({ component: AppComponent }))
      .name;
   ```
3. Configure AppModule with basic imports (BrowserModule, CommonModule, UpgradeModule). Provide the angularjs' Injector to Angular; declare an "entryComponent" and remove the default bootstrap for AppComponent.

   ```js
   @NgModule({
     imports: [BrowserModule, CommonModule, UpgradeModule], 
     declarations: [AppComponent], 
     providers: [{provide: '$scope', useExisting: '$rootScope'}], // REQUIRED
     entryComponents: [AppComponent], // ADD AN ENTRY COMPONENT 
     // bootstrap: [AppComponent] MUST BE REMOVED
   })
   ```
4. Set angularjs globally with a function provided by UpgradeModule itself and manually bootstrap Angular with DoBootstrap method provided by @angular/core.

   ```js
   export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap { 
     constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }

     public ngDoBootstrap(app: any): void {
       setAngularJSGlobal(angular);
       this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [Ng1Shared], { strictDi: false });
       app.bootstrap(AppComponent);
     }
   }
   ```
5. Create a wrapper directive for every angularjs component and add it to AppModule's declaration array.

   ```js
   @Directive({
       selector: 'my-component'
   })
   export class MyComponentWrapper extends UpgradeComponent {
       @Input() title: string;

       constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
         super('myComponent', elementRef, injector);
       }
   }
   ```

I wrote a simple [example available on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upgrade?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts). 
For example purposes I added angularjs MyCompanyModule to another angularjs module, called Ng1Module. As you can see also property binding between angularjs and angular component works fine.

I hope it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23141#issuecomment-379493753

> you cannot directly bootstrap an Angular component that contains
>   upgraded components before bootstrapping AngularJS. Instead, you can
>   downgrade AppComponent and let it be bootstrapped as part of the
>   AngularJS part of the app:
>
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djb5bu?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

try to add an entryComponents to your AppModule like this :

```
...
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, ExampleDirective],
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, UpgradeModule],
    entryComponents: [
          AppComponent // Don't forget this!!!
    ],
    providers: [],
    // bootstrap: [AppComponent] // Delete or comment this line 
})
...
```

Comment: With Ivy engine, this is no longer needed https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#entrycomponents-and-analyze_for_entry_components-no-longer-required